# Ubuntu 19.04 suddenly not able to make it to boot menu

Tags: boot, 19.04, amd-graphics, spice

I did a fresh install of 19.04 about 2-3 weeks ago (complete wipe and install on a freshly partitioned hdd, not an upgrade.)  I was pleasantly surprised at the amazing performance of the opensource AMD drivers; I was honestly expecting to have to drop back to 16.04 to get my system working.

Today, I powered up my machine, and after grub, I get the purple ubuntu screen with the white dots, but the system is completely frozen at that point.  The dots do not change to orange or anything.

No keypresses or mouse clicks are recognized, and tapping the power button does not initiate a shutdown.  I let it sit for >15 minutes, it is completely frozen.

I tried booting to the previous kernel, but no change.

I can get to a login using the recovery console and then selecting "resume" (or whatever the actual text is) and am able to get to a working system, but the video quality is horrible, colors are super-saturated, screen tearing and flickering on any video... basically the exact performance I'm used to getting with the opensourced drivers.  These are all things that were not an issue prior to today.

Checking for broken packages from the recovery console indicated that `xscreensaver` was a problem; It didn't seem that the screensaver would bork the system so bad it can't even get to the login screen, but whatever.

It said it was a problem, so I removed it just to try and get my system working.  No change, and no other broken packages after that.

The new `log file viewer` is giving me the following entries under "important:"

```
spice-vdagent  Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0

gdm-session-wor  gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file

spice-vdagent   Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0

gnome-session-b   Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop

NetworkManager   <error> [1566676018.6512] session-monitor: failed to create systemd-logind monitor: -2

(sd-executor)  /usr/lib/systemd/system-generators/friendly-recovery failed with exit status 1.

[drm:amdgpu_init [amdgpu]] *ERROR* VGACON disables amdgpu kernel modesetting.
```

For the past week, I have been getting a popup at every boot: `"System problem detected"` with only the "send" or "cancel" options; no option to show exactly what the system problem is.

I've looked up each of the errors, but cannot really find any definitive answers... Like the "spice vidagent" - remove it because you aren't using a virtual machine, but also don't remove it because the gnome desktop depends on it.  I know better to start messing with things like that until I hear from someone who actually know what they're talking about.

**Specs:**

AMD® Athlon(tm) ii x4 645 processor × 4

llvmpipe (LLVM 8.0, 128 bits)  - I don't know what that is, it used to recognize my AMD R9 380X

Gnome 3.32.1

Kernel: 5.0.0-25 generic

OS Ubuntu 19.04 x86_64

Any help in where to even begin troubleshooting this would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd start researching the last error first: `[drm:amdgpu_init [amdgpu]] *ERROR* VGACON disables amdgpu kernel modesetting.` it looks the most promising to me.

Comment: Thank you.   I have not had to use nomodeset since installing 19.04, but I have tried adding it.  It makes no difference. The only references I can find for vgacon always say that it disables modesetting... is vgacon something I can delete somehow?  I've not had to use any kernel switches before, so I'm not sure what exactly vgacon has disabled to break the system, or what any of this has to do with a screensaver.